# Wheel rotation is really sloppy

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine

For some reason my wheel rotation is really sloppy, check here:
https://gyazo.com/68f7cece87f33075841ea367372fc036

I have tried setting Origin to Median and Bounding center, nothing changed.

What could cause it?

[Google Drive .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKB3TRz_wiRQUcCQMFrYQVThNGSVoaCr/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This could also be caused by your rotation method (XYZ Euler/Quaternion etc.). Could you share your file so we can take a look? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: is the origin orientation perpendicular to the object? Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hey, I added it to the post. Hope it is okay to link it with Google Drive as pasteall only had max 25MB

Comment: Also, this happens, when I try to make the car follow the path and rotate, so it would look like it drifts: 
https://gyazo.com/3af59e3197d97dc3e4ab3598bcdef134

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Thank you! Next time I know better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the wheel, at least, it would seem that your tyre is ever so slightly oblong - possibly the whole wheel too. See screenshot:

[image]

Note that the orange highlight appears as a crescent around just part of the wheel when viewed from side on. I tried to make sure I had it flat-on when I took this screenshot, so anything like that should be perfectly symmetrical, as far as was possible.

When I rotated the wheel slowly, I noticed a bit of lateral warping along the edges, which adds more weight to my theory.

To test it, though, and put the theory to bed, I added a circle, extruded it and placed it around the wheel. See how the orange ring of the selected wheel leaves an uneven distance from the perfect circle I added?

[image]

As for how this happened, I cannot say, but it may be as simple as squashing it along the offending axis.

As for your wobble, I think it's best practice to have the axis of rotation for your wheel be the last that appears in the brackets next to 'Euler' in the rotation method. Please correct me if I have it the wrong way round.

The final problem: the weird distortion of your car. This looks on the surface to be a scaling issue. Make sure all object, empties and other dependencies have their scales applied so that they read 1:1:1 in the sidebar next to XYZ. I haven't had time to look into this, however.

Comment: You must be right; I probably have shifted it on any axis and set the scale off; it worked fine as I tried another wheel earlier. Changing the Euler seemed not to fix it, but I will use another pair of wheels then. Thanks